# Switch between databases using ajax php

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am trying to switch between databases connection ( just change hostname ) depending on chosen DB name.

I got `<a>` tags with values.

```
<div class="user-menu dropdown-menu">
    <a class="nav-link" href="db" id="db_one"><i class="fa fa-database"></i> DB 1</a>
    <a class="nav-link" href="db" id="db_two"><i class="fa fa-database"></i> DB 2</a>   
</div>
```

Now I am checking which `<a>` is clicked then taking value `db_one/db_two` and send it by ajax to my php connecting file.

Where is my fault? I still got default connection

```js
$("a[href='db']").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var hostname = e.target.id;
  console.log(hostname);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'connection.php',
    data: hostname,
    type: "post",
    success: function() {
      alert('done');
      console.log('this is: ' + hostname);
      location.reload();
    },
  });
});
```

I am reloading page to "reconnect" with db.

And finally there is my php connection.

```
<?php

    $host = $_POST['hostname'];
    $hostname = $host;

    switch ($hostname) {
      case "db_one":
        $conn = mysqli_connect("$hostname", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
        if($conn === false){
            die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
        } else {
          echo "<script>console.log('connected');</script>";
        }
        break;
      case "db_two":
        $conn = mysqli_connect("$hostname", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
        if($conn === false){

            die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());

        } else {
          echo "<script>console.log('Polaczenie z baza nawiazane');</script>";
          echo "<script>console.log('connected');</script>";

        }
        break;
      default:
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
        if($conn === false){
            die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());

        } else {
          echo "<script>console.log('default connect');</script>";

        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: `this.id` is the same as `e.target.id;`

Comment: This is easy to do but first you must look into its security implications

Comment: Shouldn't it be `data: {hostname:hostname}`?

Comment: @Defuse `select` dropdown would have been a better option.

Comment: _This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers._

Comment: This sounds dangerous. Why use a POST as an array for the host? You should be using a prepared statement for this.

Comment: There is no actual query here so it can't be parameterized. It does sound like a bad security policy though.

Comment: I know that it's unsecured but I just want to make test with switching databases then rewrite it the right way

Comment: @Defus Should this by chance (also) be an PHP issue, add the following just under your opening `<?php` tag: `ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);`. You should also look at your developer console.

Comment: hey is this always connect on your default case right

Comment: @MahfuzarRahman yes u right

Comment: try my answer..

Comment: Nothing. I am pretty sure that my hostname is empty because Notice: Undefined index: hostname in /srv/test/db.php on line 6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

now use this full code

```
<?php
if ((function_exists('session_status') //start session if not started
  && session_status() !== PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE) || !session_id()) {
 $lifetime=strtotime('+7 days', 0);
  session_set_cookie_params($lifetime);
  session_start();
} if(isset($_POST['hostname'])){
    $_SESSION['hostname']=$_POST['hostname'];
}  $hostname =$_SESSION['hostname'];

    switch ($hostname) {
      case "db_one":
        $conn = mysqli_connect("$hostname", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
        if($conn === false){
            die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
        } else {
          echo "<script>console.log('connected');</script>";
        }
        break;
      case "db_two":
        $conn = mysqli_connect("$hostname", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
        if($conn === false){

            die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());

        } else {
          echo "<script>console.log('Polaczenie z baza nawiazane');</script>";
          echo "<script>console.log('connected');</script>";

        }
        break;
      default:
        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "my_user", "my_password", "my_db");
        if($conn === false){
            die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());

        } else {
          echo "<script>console.log('default connect');</script>";

        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: Nothing. I am pretty sure that my hostname is empty because Notice: Undefined index: hostname in /srv/test/db.php on line 6

Comment: which variable u using and did your server support php session and if supported are you started session

Comment: Should I start session in my file where I got ajax? How?

Comment: replace your php server side code with my edited code

Comment: Dude it works. But for example if I choose something with wrong value - so I can't connect to db. I am getting error ERROR: Could not connect. php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
and what now? I must wait 7 days?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184227/discussion-between-mahfuzar-rahman-and-defus).

Comment: Is it any possible option to click: Back to default db?

Comment: yes just add this link `<a class="nav-link" href="db" id="db_defult"><i class="fa fa-database"></i> DB 1</a>`

Answer (score 1):

You aren't sending a key/value pair....only a value.

Change

```
data: hostname
```

To

```
data: {hostname:hostname}
```

Comment: Really worth an answer?

Comment: Still I got only default case

Comment: @Defus Let's narrow down the issue then. Line one of PHP `die(print_r($_POST));` if the value is not there the question doesn't need the PHP because it is a JS transmission issue.

Comment: @user3783243 where put it? I am connecting to db because default value

Comment: @Defus On line 1 after the first `<?php`.

Comment: @user3783243 Array
(
)
1

Comment: @Defus, Okay, so the PHP is not relevant to the question (or at least currently). Open the developer console and look at what is happening. (Your PHP could roughly be switched to https://3v4l.org/3V7uR which will be more secure and easier to read) Maybe `e.target.id` is incorrect, I usually do `$(this).attr('value')` I'm js guessing though

Comment: @Defus I can't see you console so can't say. What are the form values it says it is sending?

Comment: @user3783243 nothig just: This is: db_one

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to send the ajax request:

```
$("a[href='db']").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var hostname = this.id;
  console.log(hostname);
  $.ajax({
    url: 'connection.php',
    data: {'hostname': hostname},
    type: "post",
    success: function() {
      alert('done');
      console.log('this is: ' + hostname);
      location.reload();
    },
  });
});
```

Hope this will solve the problem